# Get RGB intensity from image swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I know that the question is already asked but I don't understand.
I want to create a function:

```
func getRGBAsFromImage(    )-> (NSArray*){}
```

But I don't arrive  to implement that with this answer.

```
+ (NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)x andY:(int)y count:(int)count
{
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
// First get the image into your data buffer
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);
// Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
NSUInteger byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
{
CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex + 3] ) / 255.0f;
CGFloat red = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex] ) / alpha;
CGFloat green = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex + 1] ) / alpha;
CGFloat blue = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex + 2] ) / alpha;
byteIndex += bytesPerPixel;
UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
[result addObject:acolor];
}
free(rawData);
return result;
}
```

How to do that?